# cx_oracle executes without error, but does not delete data

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I would to remove all customers who's names begin with SCH from my database. When I execute the code below it runs without error, but does not remove the data from the database.

```
cur = db.cursor()
sql = "DELETE FROM customers where IMAGE_ID like 'SCH%'"
cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: How does cx_oracle commit transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after delete you need `commit`

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(...)
cur = db.cursor()
sql = "DELETE FROM customers where IMAGE_ID like 'SCH%'"
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Depending how many SQL statements are used for each DB transaction, might want to look at [autocommiting](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/connection.html#Connection.autocommit), since this will save a 'round-trip' to the database over calling `commit()` separately.